# Using absolute and relative position to configure a dynamic sidebar

Tags: css, css-position

I'm getting a little confused with using Absolute and Relative positioning. Basically I have a sidebar which has roughly 4 divs in it.

I want div 3 to always be at the same place on every page, as occasionally div 1 or div 2 are missing, which in turn pulls div 3 up.

I tried adding position: relative to the sidebar, and position: absolute to div 3. This puts it in the correct place on the sidebar, but it makes div 3 overlap the other divs.

What am I missing out here?

---

Layout for anyone confused:

```
 <div id='sidebar'>
        <div id='div1'></div>
        <div id='div2'></div>
        <div id='div3'></div>
        <div id='div4'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how absolute positioning is supposed to work - the absolutely positioned element is removed from the content flow, and takes up no space - so it can't push the elements down.

You're going to need to use some sort of placeholder, or come up with something using margins. I'm not sure about how your elements need to be placed, but, if `div3` always has to be, say, `400px` from the top, why don't you do it like this:

```
<div id='sidebar'>
    <div style="height:400px">
        <div id='div1'></div>
        <div id='div2'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='div3'></div>
    <div id='div4'></div>
</div>
```

This way, you can hide `div1` and `div2` at will, without the need to use absolute positioning at all.

Comment: I was trying to go with CSS as it is actually Blocks in a Drupal Sidebar, which makes this harder than just adding a couple of lines (Changing theme templates moving blocks etc). Still, I'm gonna give it a shot. Good answer +1

Answer (score 1):

I just tried hiding #div1,2,4 using visibility styling and it didn't move any of the other div's

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/hq6LM/10/

The reason for this is cause if you style using visibility it still retains it's block properties and the div's wont be moved up because they're still there just invisible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh but you see if there missing, then there won't be any actual content to make 'visible'. If they were just been hidden then this would be a fine solution.